# can i use android aide for learning java

Tags: java, android

Ok so this time I will make it  more specific.

I want to learn Java only. So I have bought myself a book on Java programming and would like to follow the examples in the book. For doing this on the go (because I don't always have access to my PC) I've downloaded [AIDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=en), which is basically an IDE for Android phones.

But this app seems to be for android development only. Can I use this to practice Java? Because now when I write anything in Java and compile it, it only outputs what's in the layout XML.

Comment: You can download eclipse by itself, without the ADT plugin. Just make a new Java project instead of an Android project

Comment: and again, Eclipse is available on all platforms

Comment: @Jeeter Not on all platforms. It is not available on Android. Besides, people who primarily use AIDE generally don't have access to a Windows/Linux/Mac (at least me, anyway, I refuse to fork up $300-400 for a computer just to run home made apps).

Answer (score 7):

If you want to learn Java, then use a PC, not a mobile device.

While Android apps are written in Java, Android does not support the full set of Java APIs. For example, any program using awt classes will not run on Android, as Android's UI framework is completely different.

I would strongly suggest you use a PC and an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ to learn at least core Java before coming to Android app development. It will make your life much much easier if you know Java syntax and the basic core of the language well before you attempt Android development.

Here is a list of the Java packages that are included in the standard Java on your PC, but not part of the Android APIs (it may be a little outdated, but it should give you an idea of the differences):

```
java.applet
java.awt (except for the font classes)
java.beans
java.lang.management
java.rmi
javax.accessibility
javax.activity
javax.imageio
javax.management
javax.naming
javax.print
javax.rmi
javax.security.auth.kerberos
javax.security.auth.spi
javax.security.sasl
javax.swing
javax.transaction
javax.xml (except javax.xml.parsers)
org.ietf.*
org.omg.*
org.w3c.dom.* (sub-packages)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is all I needed to hear. I'll have to dust off the laptop. Thanks again

Comment: Actually I believe Android uses the font objects in the awt package.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for may be possible, but is not recommended.

Android programming requires a lot of specialized knowledge specifically about how to program for Android, and this requirement will get in your way when trying to learn basic Java.

Learn Java first, then, if desired, learn how to apply that knowledge to Android programming.