# a very simple ques-tion,but i don't know

Tags: java

This is a example of [Introduction to Java Programming(Eighth Edition)]
But when I input on my IDE ,It tell me it's. error

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class DialogBox
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
                 JOptionPaneshowMessageDialog(null,"Hello ");

    }
}
```

Two error one is swing
the other is second JOptionPane.

Comment: Please give your questions a title that indicates the content of the question. Don't use the same title for every question you post.

Comment: If you have compile errors, please include the text of the error in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and see. Don't forget the .(dot) in JOptionPane.show....

```
   import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

   public class DialogBox
   {
       public static void main(String[]args)
       {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hello ");

       }
   }
```

Comment: I only create one class,

Comment: It also have two errors like myself. Code

Comment: @desi Didn't get your question at all. What are you trying to do with those classes and what are the errors say? What is the IDE you use?

Comment: @DeSI In The code edited by Thush-Fdo , closely check the dot(.) after JOptionPane , add that and execute , it should execute perfectly.

Comment: Oh.The book of (Introduction to Java Programming(Eighth Edition)) have a example than I input the example,But I don't know why It's Have two errors,one is the"unknown type or package 'swing '

Comment: The other is "unknown entity 'JOptionPane '

Comment: Because I am a Chinese(senior high school)

Comment: My computer at my home,But i live at school, So i learn java at my Android Device. my IDE is AIDE

Comment: @desi The best way to learn java is by using a PC with a good IDE without using a mobile phone. Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14113356/5850835) Accordingly javax.swing is not supported by AIDE it seems

Comment: Ok,Thanks for you help!